# Me esta llegando la interfaz nula, no puedo poner el constructor porque se me rompe el manifest y no me deja pasar parámetros por el intent

Tags: java, android-studio

Por acá  mando los parámetros de la clase Master para PunteModal

```
public class MasterController extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, IMasterController {

       protected void goToSeleccionarMetodoModal(Cuenta cuenta,SolicitantesModel solicitud, TipoTransaccionEnum tipoTransaccion) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MasterController.this,
                    PuenteModal.class);
        
            solicitud.setImage("");
             intent.putExtra("SolicitudCuenta", cuenta);
            intent.putExtra("SolicitudActividad", solicitud);
            intent.putExtra("tipoTransaccion", tipoTransaccion);
        
            startActivity(intent);
        }

}
```

Mando los parametros a la clase PunteModal pero al mandar la interfaz esta vacia, porque no la puedo recibir a causa de no tener el constructor, como podría pasar los parámetros q recibo en PunteModal a otro controlador Modal

```
public class PuenteModal extends MasterController  {

    IPasarAModal IPasarModal;
    Cuenta cuenta;
    TipoTransaccionEnum retiro;
    SolicitantesModel solicitud;

    public PuenteModal() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background));

            Cuenta cuenta = (Cuenta) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("SolicitudCuenta");
            SolicitantesModel solicitud=(SolicitantesModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("SolicitudActividad");
            TipoTransaccionEnum tipoTransaccion = (TipoTransaccionEnum) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("tipoTransaccion");
            IPasarModal.mostrarListaPasarAModal(cuenta,solicitud,retiro);
        }
    }
}
```

Por ultimo la clase Modal que necesito volver con los parámetros : Cuenta , tipoTransaccion, solicitud Probe pasandolo de Master pero al no poder extender de ella no me deja recibir parametros por culpa  de BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
public class AceptarRechazarCobroModal extends BottomSheetDialogFragment implements IaceptarCobroDevolver,IAceptarCobro, IPasarAModal {

    SolicitantesModel solicitudModel;
    IAccionesHomeController iAcciones;
    ElegirCuentasACobrar bottomSheet;

    IPasarAModal IPasarM;
Cuenta cuentaDevuelta;
    private IaceptarCobroDevolver iaceptarCobroDevolver;
    Cuenta lstCuentas;
    ElegirCuentasACobrar cobrar;
  //  IAceptarCobro iAceptarCobro;
    TipoTransaccionEnum tipoVuelta;

    public AceptarRechazarCobroModal() {

    }


    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        BottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.solicitud_de_cobro, null);
        bottomSheet.setContentView(view);

        TextView strLblName = view.findViewById(R.id.nombre_solicitante);
        TextView strLblMonto = view.findViewById(R.id.monto_solicitud);
        TextView strLblRef = view.findViewById(R.id.ref_solicitud);
        TextView btnRechazar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_rechazar);
        ImageView btn_close = view.findViewById(R.id.close_bottomsheet);
        ImageView btn_select_method = view.findViewById(R.id.imgSelectMethod);
        IPasarM = this;
        ImageView fotoPerfil = view.findViewById(R.id.foto_solicitante);
        final SeekBar seekBarPagar = view.findViewById(R.id.SeekBarContinuar);
        iniComponentes();
        strLblName.setText(solicitudModel.getFirstName());
        strLblMonto.setText(formateadorDeSaldos(solicitudModel.getMonto()));
        strLblRef.setText(solicitudModel.getDetalle());

       // if (getIntent().getSerializableExtra("SolicitudCuenta") != null) {
        //    Cuenta cuenta = (Cuenta) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cuentaElegida");
        //    lstCuentas=cuenta;

       // }


        if(!solicitudModel.getImage().equals("") || solicitudModel.getImage() != null){
            if (!solicitudModel.getImage().equals("s/d")) {
                fotoPerfil.setImageBitmap(ImageUtil.convert(solicitudModel.getImage()));
            }
        }



        btn_select_method.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //  solicitudModel.setImage("");
               iAcciones.mostrarListaTarjetasCuentas(solicitudModel,IPasarM);
                // cobrar=new ElegirCuentasACobrar(solicitudModel,AceptarRechazarCobroModal.this);
            }
        });

}
```

En esta clase que contiene una lista manda los datos a la master :

```
public class ElegirCuentasACobrar extends MasterController implements View.OnClickListener,IAceptarCobro {

 @Override
public void origenSeleccionadoAceptarCobro(Cuenta cuenta, TipoTransaccionEnum retiro) {

    goToSeleccionarMetodoModal(cuenta,solicitud,retiro);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que lo que tratas de enviar son objetos y los tratas de enviar mediante un `Intent`, pero en este caso a una clase que no es un `Activity`:

```
public class PuenteModal extends MasterController  {
```

Lo que debes realizar es crear un constructor, para enviar los valores, aquí incluso puedes enviar la interfaz:

```
public class PuenteModal extends MasterController  {

    IPasarAModal IPasarModal;
    Cuenta cuenta;
    TipoTransaccionEnum retiro;
    SolicitantesModel solicitud;

    public PuenteModal(Cuenta cuenta,SolicitantesModel solicitud, TipoTransaccionEnum tipoTransaccion, IPasarAModal IPasarModal) {
      this.cuenta = cuenta;
      this.solicitud = solicitud;
      this.tipoTransaccion = retiro;
      this.IPasarModal = IPasarModal;
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...


}
```

ahora este sería tu método, donde no debes olvidar iniciar previamente la interfaz

```
protected void goToSeleccionarMetodoModal(cuenta, solicitud, tipoTransaccion) {
        PuenteModal puenteModal = new PuenteModal(cuenta, solicitud, tipoTransaccion, IPasarModal);
    }
```

Comment: Modifique la pregunta, para que veas que el intent esta en una master que extiende de activity, se me rompe la app cuando llega a :  IPasarModal.mostrarListaPasarAModal(cuenta,solicitud,retiro);  de la clase PuenteModal  .           
Porque la interfaz IPasarModal llega null , y nose como llegar con los datos de los parámetros a la clase :AceptarRechazarCobroModal